# WinApi , SetWindowPos не работает

Tags: c#, winapi

Нужно перетащить окно игры CSGO , использовал SetWindowPos  , для других окон мой код работает , а для игры не работает 
`[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
        public static extern IntPtr SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int x, int Y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);`
Импортирую функцию

```
try
            {
                var chromeDriverProcesses = Process.GetProcesses().
                                                      Where(pr => pr.ProcessName == "csgo");
                const short SWP_NOMOVE = 0X2;
                const short SWP_NOSIZE = 1;
                const short SWP_NOZORDER = 0X4;
                const int SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;

                foreach (var processx in chromeDriverProcesses)
                {
                    richTextBox1.AppendText(processx.MainWindowTitle );
                    SetWindowPos(processx.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }`
```

Comment: Может быть потому что вы пытаетесь задать нулевой размер и нулевые координаты? (Зачем ботоводить в игре где должен проявляться твой личный и командный скилл?)

Comment: Пробовали с ненулевыми координатами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все работает , код верный, прогу надо запускать с правами администратора, тогда все будет работать.